# Advice on optimal looping of XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an issue where I need to loop through a lot of lines and format particular items in each line which correspond to the word item.

I am able to loop and figured out how to apply the formatting. But my issue is: the item appears at the end of the line when I apply the XSLT transform.

Below I have included my code.
I am using the XML functions `for-each`, `value-of` and `if`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL    /Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html>
      <body> 
        <h2>Title</h2> 
          <xsl:for-each select="song/l"> 
             <p> 
               <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
               <xsl:if test="verb">
                  <span style="color:#ff0000"> 
                    <i><xsl:value-of select="verb"/></i>
                 </span>
               </xsl:if>              
            </p>   
          </xsl:for-each>    
        </body>
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<song> 
   <l n="1">The fox <verb>jumps</verb> up high</l> 
   <l n="2">The frog is greener than a forest.</l> 
</song>
```

What I am hoping to achieve is:
For example, in a line such as

```
"The Brown fox jumps up high"
```

The word `jump` is labeled as a verb and should be in a different color and italicized.

My code right now displays

```
"The Brown fox jumps up high. jumps"
```

Formatted correctly.
I need it to keep jumps in the same position in the line as is.
Any help or advice appreciated.

Comment: Oops, Sorry. The input is

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <song> 
       <l n="1">The fox <verb>jumps</verb> up high</l> 
       <l n="1">The frog is greener than a forest.</l> 
    </song>

Comment: Honestly, this is 'bread & butter' even to XSLT 1.0. You CAN use 2.0 or 3.0, but it's simple enough that you really don't need the advanced features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a simple case of applying an appropriate template to your various elements, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html>
      <body> 
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="song/l"/>
      </body>
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="verb">
    <span style="color:#ff0000; font-style:italic;">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="l">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(I tweaked it slightly to use `font-style:italic;` rather than the `<i/>` element, but you could easily just put the `<i>` just inside the span)